# 1st order Integro-differential Equation for 3D printing prediction

Tags: python, math, ode, differential-equations

I apologize if this is a fairly simple question. I'm an engineer, and I've just started learning python, so I'm probably missing something very obvious.

I have an Integro-differential equation I am trying to solve with solve_ivp for the ODE, and quad for the integral with-in the ODE. I can't seem to get it to work, I have solved the ODE with mu as a constant, but now mu is variable it must be solved with in integral in place of it. This is the equation where mu is constant.

[image: Image of Simple ODE]

The constants are:

```py
kI_0 = 0.0015
μ = 3.74
z = np.linspace(0, 1.15, 100)
```

The Code to solve this is this:

```py
import numpy as np
import math as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

#requires np.exp() overwise it doesnt work. 
def dϕdt(t, ϕ, kI_0, μ, z):
    return kI_0*(1-ϕ)*np.exp(-μ*z)

kI_0 = 0.0015
μ = 3.74

#Set the initial conditions as a vector of 100 zeros. Vector is required because its creating an array and isnt a scalar. 
ϕ = np.zeros(100)

#linspace from 0 to 1.15 with 100 increment inbetween.     
z = np.linspace(0, 1.15, 100) 

#used t_span and dont define the increment size in t_span because then the function will select an appropriate size. 
#use args to set the addional arguments with the ODE solver function. 
sol_m1 = solve_ivp(dϕdt, y0=ϕ, t_span=(0, 3600), args=(kI_0, μ, z))

#Select the full row of the last column of y to get the finally results for
#y because I need the full conversion fraction value which is 1 when the full time has elapsed. 
#this can be checked by changing the row (-1) to (1), this shows that only 1*10^-7 is the conversion fraction.  
plt.plot(z, sol_m1.y[:,-1])
plt.ylabel("Conversion Fraction")
plt.xlabel("Moving Solid Liquid Interface (mm)")
plt.title("Liquid Conversion Fraction vs Depth \n (Numerically Solved)")
print(sol_m1)
#sol_m2
```

This code works fine and solves this simpler ODE numerically.

However, with the mu now as a variable, the equation is this:
[Image of Integro-differential to solve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOLd6.png)

mu can be written as the equation:

```py
μ = μ_0*(1 - ϕ) + μ_infny*ϕ
```

Where ϕ is produced from the solved ODE on each time step.
The constants are:

```py
μ_0 = 1
μ_infny = 5
kI_0 = 0.0015
```

The attempted code I've written is the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import math as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sy
import scipy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import cumulative_trapezoid

μ_0 = 1
μ_infny = 5
kI_0 = 0.0015


def μ(ϕ, μ_0, μ_infny):
    return μ_0*(1 - ϕ) + μ_infny*ϕ 


#Set the initial conditions as a vector of 100 zeros. Vector is required because its creating an array and isnt a scalar. 
ϕ = np.zeros(100)

#linspace from 0 to 1.15 with 100 increment inbetween.     
z = np.linspace(0, 1.15, 100) 

#create function for intergral

f = lambda z : -μ(ϕ, μ_0, μ_infny)
Int = quad(f, 0, 1.15)

#requires np.exp() overwise it doesnt work. 
def dϕdt(t, ϕ, kI_0, Int):
    return kI_0*(1-ϕ)*np.exp(Int)


#used t_span and dont define the increment size in t_span because then the function will select an appropriate size. 
#use args to set the additional arguments with the ODE solver function. 
   sol_m1 = solve_ivp(dϕdt, y0=ϕ, t_span=(0, 3600), args=(kI_0, Int))
  

#Select the full row of the last column of y to get the finally results for
#y because I need the full conversion fraction value which is 1 when the full time has elapsed. 
#this can be checked by changing the row (-1) to (1), this shows that only 1*10^-7 is the conversion fraction.  
plt.plot(z, sol_m1.y[:,-1])
plt.ylabel("Conversion Fraction")
plt.xlabel("Moving Solid Liquid Interface (mm)")
plt.title("Liquid Conversion Fraction vs Depth \n (Numerically Solved)")
print(sol_m1)
#sol_m2
```

Has anyone any idea on how to solve this numerically?

It should produce a graph similar to this:
[Graph of what the simple ODE produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to1dx.png)
From the attempted code this is the result:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: I'm not an expert, but my understanding is that integral equations require a different approach. From what I remember, the most straightforward approach is to create a vector of unknown values phi(0), phi(1), phi(2), ..., phi(n) to make a piecewise approximation to the function phi, and then try to derive a system of equations from that. Looks like exp(phi) appears in your problem, maybe to make progress you can linearize that to 1 + phi and hope that phi is close to zero. There might be specialized solvers for integro-differential equations such that you don't need to work out the details.